# Optimizing PHP algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I have built a class that finds the smallest number divisible by a all numbers in a given range.

This is my code:

```
class SmallestDivisible
{

    private $dividers = array();

    public function findSmallestDivisible($counter)
    {
        $this->dividers = range(10, 20);

        for($x=1; $x<$counter; $x++) {

            if ($this->testIfDevisibleByAll($x, $this->dividers) == true) {
                return $x;
            }
        }
    }

    private function testIfDevisibleByAll($x, $dividers)
    {
        foreach($dividers as $divider) {
            if ($x % $divider !== 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

$n = new SmallestDivisible();

echo $n->findSmallestDivisible(1000000000);
```

This class finds a number that is divisible by all numbers in the range from 1 to 20 (`$this->dividers`).

I know it works well as I tested it with other, lower ranges, but, unfortunately, it is not able to find the solution for `range(10, 20)` within 30 seconds - and this is the time after which a PHP script is halted.

A parameter that is fed to the `findSmallestDivisible` method is the ceiling of the group of numbers the script is going to inspect (e.i. from 1 to `$counter` (1000000000 is this execution)).

I would be grateful for suggestions on how I can optimize this script so that it executes faster.

Comment: How long does it take now?  How long do you want it to take?

Comment: Consider asking optimization questions for working code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: (Also, _the time after which a PHP script is halted_ is [configurable](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time))

Comment: @kojiro, I really wish for the script to execute within 30 seconds time limit.

Comment: @andy, I know only that the script doesn't find the sought after number within 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is brute-force and simply horrible.

Instead, how about handling it mathematically? You're looking for the lowest common multiple of numbers in your range, so...

```
function gcd($n, $m) {
   $n=abs($n); $m=abs($m);
   list($n,$m) = array(min($m,$n),max($m,$n));
   while($r = $m % $n) {
      list($m,$n) = array($n,$r);
   }
   return $n;
}
function lcm($n, $m) {
   return $m * ($n/gcd($n,$m));
}

function lcm_array($arr) {
   while(count($arr) > 1) {
      array_push($arr, lcm(array_shift($arr),array_shift($arr)));
   }
   return array_shift($arr);
}

var_dump(lcm_array(range(10,20)));
// result int(232792560)
```

This means your original code would have had to do 232,792,560 iterations, no wonder it took so long!

Comment: This is surely the way to go. I really need to practice my mathematical-thinking skills. I tend to write brute-force algorithms for problems that I encounter. They often work, but they are not I wish to write my name under :) Thank you!

Comment: @niet, could you possibly provide some explanation on what your code does in each step - maybe in the form of in-code comments?

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is an easy mathematical calculation named [the least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) but using brute force to compute it is totally wrong (as you already found out).

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) lists several reasonable algorithms that can be used to compute it faster.

The one explained in the section "[A method using a table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#A_method_using_a_table)" is really fast and doesn't require much memory. You keep only the leftmost column of the table (the numbers you want to get the `lcm` for) and the rightmost column (the current step). If you implement it I suggest you hardcode a list of [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) into your program to avoid computing them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I came up with.

In short, the algorithm will calculate LCM (lesast common multiple) for a group of numbers.

```
class Lcmx
{

    public $currentLcm = 0;

    private function gcd($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a == 0 || $b == 0)
            return abs( max(abs($a), abs($b)) );

        $r = $a % $b;
        return ($r != 0) ?
            $this->gcd($b, $r) :
            abs($b);
    }   

    private function lcm($a, $b)
    {
        return array_product(array($a, $b)) / $this->gcd($a, $b);
    }

    public function lcm_array($array = array())
    {
        $factors = $array;  
        while(count($factors) > 1) {

            $this->currentLcm = $this->lcm(array_pop($factors), array_pop($factors));
            array_push($factors, $this->currentLcm);
        }

        return $this;

    }
}

$l = new Lcmx;
echo $l->lcm_array(range(1, 20))->currentLcm;
//232792560
```